# Set the layout weight of an EditText programmatically

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

I want to have two columns of EditTexts in a horizontal layout, that is inside a root layout. in the designer i added a button to add two EditTexts, however I cant find a way to edit the android:layout_weight programatically.

My code is

```
    private void BtnAddSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.Text = "";

        editText.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 0.3f);

        var editText2 = new EditText(this);
        editText2.Text = "";

        editText2.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 0.3f);


        var horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        horizontalLayout.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        horizontalLayout.AddView(editText);
        horizontalLayout.AddView(editText2);

        this.rootLayout.AddView(horizontalLayout);
    }
```

Comment: How do you mean, exactly? The third argument in the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` constructor you're using there is the weight.

Comment: true, and it splits the EditText evenly, but if i set it to 0,3f (33% of the screen width) it still is 50%. am i misunderstanding the concept of weight? i want the EditText to be same width no matter screen size

Comment: Ah, yeah, just a slight misunderstanding. You've got the basic gist; you're just missing the weight sum on the `LinearLayout` itself. If you don't explicitly set that, it will be implicitly set to the sum of all the children's weights. In your case, the weight sum ends up being 0.6, and with each `EditText` at 0.3, they end up getting half the space. If you want each to be a third of the `LinearLayout`, explicitly set the `LinearLayout`'s `WeightSum` (or however it is in C#) to `1f` (and maybe change the weights to `0.33f`, to be more accurate).

Comment: The width remains the same, half the screen. I'll have to expeeiment